My printer is not working
My printer worked for 6 months without any problems، but now it doesn't work.
My printer:
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04e8:342e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd SCX-4300 Series

My printer is working properly. The problem is CUPS.
When I print a file، the image is displayed below.

I use ppd file for driver. It worked in 6 months
CUPS debbug mode
Page 1 (<troubleshoot.SchedulerNotRunning.SchedulerNotRunning object at 0x7faa00118390>):
{'cups_connection_failure': False}
Page 2 (<troubleshoot.CheckLocalServerPublishing.CheckLocalServerPublishing object at 0x7faa00118750>):
{'local_server_exporting_printers': False}
Page 3 (<troubleshoot.ChoosePrinter.ChoosePrinter object at 0x7faa00118cd0>):
{'cups_dest': <cups.Dest SCX-4300-Series (default)>,
 'cups_instance': None,
 'cups_queue': 'SCX-4300-Series',
 'cups_queue_listed': True}
Page 4 (<troubleshoot.CheckPrinterSanity.CheckPrinterSanity object at 0x7faa0011a510>):
{'cups_device_uri_scheme': 'usb',
 'cups_printer_dict': {'device-uri': 'usb://Samsung/SCX-4300%20Series?serial=146TBFES500061W.&interface=1',
                       'printer-info': 'Samsung SCX-4300 Series',
                       'printer-is-shared': True,
                       'printer-location': 'debian',
                       'printer-make-and-model': 'Samsung SCX-4300 Series',
                       'printer-state': 3,
                       'printer-state-message': 'Rendering completed',
                       'printer-state-reasons': ['none'],
                       'printer-type': 135236,
                       'printer-uri-supported': 'ipp://localhost/printers/SCX-4300-Series'},
 'cups_printer_remote': False,
 'is_cups_class': False,
 'local_cups_queue_attributes': {'charset-configured': 'utf-8',
                                 'charset-supported': ['us-ascii', 'utf-8'],
                                 'color-supported': False,
                                 'compression-supported': ['none', 'gzip'],
                                 'copies-default': 1,
                                 'copies-supported': (1, 9999),
                                 'cups-version': '2.4.7',
                                 'device-uri': 'usb://Samsung/SCX-4300%20Series?serial=146TBFES500061W.&interface=1',
                                 'document-format-default': 'application/octet-stream',
                                 'document-format-preferred': 'application/pdf',
                                 'document-format-supported': ['application/octet-stream',
                                                               'application/pdf',
                                                               'application/postscript',
                                                               'application/vnd.adobe-reader-postscript',
                                                               'application/vnd.cups-pdf',
                                                               'application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner',
                                                               'application/vnd.cups-postscript',
                                                               'application/vnd.cups-raster',
                                                               'application/vnd.cups-raw',
                                                               'application/x-cshell',
                                                               'application/x-csource',
                                                               'application/x-perl',
                                                               'application/x-shell',
                                                               'image/gif',
                                                               'image/jpeg',
                                                               'image/png',
                                                               'image/pwg-raster',
                                                               'image/tiff',
                                                               'image/urf',

